# django Postgres ArrayField preserving list insert ordering

Tags: django, postgresql

I am looking to use an `ArrayField` in Django, and I was wondering if this field preserves the order of insertion. So, for example, if I insert the list:

```
["stackoverflow", "is", "awesome"]
```

I would like to have the exact same ordering when I retrieve this `pkid`.

I have looked around the django docs and I see no mention of preserving insert order and hence my question. It would be great if someone can link me to the django docs for this.

PS: I presume JSONField will NOT preserve order and thus looking into ArrayField.

Comment: Python lists preserve order. When you save one into an postgresql array, the order is also preserved. That's also the case with `JSONField` if you pass it a list or one of the values is a list. I don't know what you mean by "insert order", you just write or retrieve the entire array/list when accessing it.

Comment: @dirkgroten: thank you for this. I did not know `JSONField` will also preserve the order of the list in which it is inserted (insert order). So if, I use a `JSONField` with default=list and then insert `["stackoverflow", "is", "awesome"]` (say pkid=1) am I always guaranteed to get this exact sequence of strings when I query this pkid=1?

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "insert order". If you **set** the model field equal to a python list `["stackoverflow", "is", "awesome"]`, then when you retrieve the field later from the database, you'll get the exact same list, i.e also the same order of the elements in the list.

Comment: I think we mean the same when we mean `insert order` and `set`. So, first I declare a `JSONField` like so: `some_field = JSONField(blank=True, default=list)` and then I `insert` (or `set`) I presume, `["stackoverflow", "is", "awesome"]` as one row using `ModelForms`. Is this a bit clearer now? By insert order I just mean `list[0]="stackoverflow" list[1]="is" list[2]= "awesome"`

Comment: Yes, correct, when you retrieve the row, the order for this field will be the same as when you wrote it.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know this. Can you please write this as an answer and I will accept it? also, I was wondering if the doc explicitly mentions this somewhere? or is it too obvious that only daft people like me ask :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) says that an `ArrayField` is

> a field for storing ***lists*** of data

Now a python `list` constructor preserves the order, as mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list):

> The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable’s items

Finally, if you look at the postgresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/arrays.html) for arrays, although order isn't mentioned explicitly, it's clear from the examples that a value stored at index `i` will be always found at the same index when retrieving it. It's probably not mentioned because in **every** programming language, arrays (called **lists** in python) preserve the order of the elements :-)

So basically, if you assign the field of your model a `list` and write it to the db, then you can be sure that when you retrieve it, you'll get the same `list`, i.e. with the order of elements preserved.

Comment: I have one follow up question (more to get your opinion): if I have a list to store, which one is prefered? ArrayField or JSONField?

Comment: ArrayField. Makes it clearer what the purpose is and won't be abused later to store other stuff (dictionaries) by maintainers of your code, which might break things.